# How to resume broken download between a c# server and Java client

Tags: c#, java, http, file-transfer

I have a client application running in Java that sends HTTP REST commands to a web service in c#.

The client downloads files from the server and it works very well.

Here's my code for the file transfer :

**Java Client**

```
public void downloadFile(String fileUrl, String fileName, String filePath) throws IOException{
        int bytesRead;
        URL url = new URL(fileUrl);

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(fileBuffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(fileBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        bos.close();
        bis.close();
    }
```

**C# web service**

```
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "SendFile/{clientID}/{fileName}")]
        public Stream sendFile(String clientID, String fileName)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.Expires, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"));
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Stream ms = File.OpenRead(@jobRepPath + fileName.Replace("___", "."));
            return ms;
        }
```

Now, based on this, I want to set up methods to resume the download of broken downloads.

I tried this code :

**Java client**

```
public void resumeBrokenDownload(String fileUrl, String fileName, String filePath, long fileLength) throws IOException{
        int bytesRead;
        URL url = new URL(fileUrl);

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath, true));

        byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[1024];     
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(fileBuffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(fileBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        bos.close();
        bis.close();
    }
```

**C# web service**

```
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "ResumeDownload/{clientID}/{fileName}/{startByte}")]
        public Stream resumeDownload(String clientID, String fileName, String startByte)
        {
            Stream ms = File.OpenRead(@jobRepPath + fileName.Replace("___", "."));
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            ms.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            Byte[] byteFile = memoryStream.ToArray();

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.Write(byteFile, Convert.ToInt32(startByte), byteFile.Length);

            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.Expires, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"));
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            return stream;
        }
```

the startByte value passed in the REST URL being the length of the part of the file already received by the client.

But this doesn't seems to work at all, I receive an empty stream from the server.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this code to work, or maybe a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem adapting the example found in [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2012/02/23/more-about-rest-file-upload-download-service-with-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-phone-background-file-transfer.aspx).

For those who are interested in my solution, I change the code of the c# web service :

```
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "ResumeDownload/{clientID}/{fileName}/{startByte}")]
        public Stream resumeDownload(String clientID, String fileName, String startByte)
        {
            MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream();
            Stream fileStream = File.Open(@jobRepPath + fileName.Replace("___", "."), FileMode.Open);

            fileStream.Seek(Convert.ToInt32(startByte), SeekOrigin.Begin);

            int length = (int)(fileStream.Length - Convert.ToInt32(startByte));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            responseStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

            fileStream.Close();
            responseStream.Position = 0;

            return responseStream; 
        }
```